# Django 1.7 vs Django1.6 vs Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-south, django-1.5, django-1.6

I have been developing using Django 1.5 a lot. Is it worth the time to shift from Django 1.5 to Django 1.6 or Django 1.7? I know, In 1.7, migration is into the core of Django. How different is it from south?

Comment: Seems a premature rush to close (less than 5 hours) on this question (probably due to the holidays and lots of free time).  This is not comparing competing frameworks, but looking for the rational about upgrading a framework they already enjoy.  None of those that closed this question are even involved with Django as evidenced by the questions and answers they participate in, and the asker appears to be a newcomer (at least to this site, quite possibly to the framework.  Maybe those involved in closing this question could stick to things they actually work with.

Comment: You thought you'd get away with this kind of question on Christmas day? LOL!! Putting a **vs** in a question is like waving a red flag to SO moderator bulls. What were you thinking? The sheer chutzpah!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Django 1.6 is a relatively incremental update compared to Django 1.7.

Django 1.6 adds a few comfort features (i.e., simplified project templates and admin enabling by default) for new projects, and some minor overhauls in algorithms (i.e., model save). There are also a myriad of other features that make development relatively easier when compared to 1.5.

Django 1.7, as you've noted, includes the migration features. In addition, it forces Python 2.7 (which may or may not be an issue for you). The migration is based off of South, so it's similar to use. In addition to various improvements, the plugin focused on being database agnostic, improved autodetection and improved the migration file format.

With both of these updates, your workflow shouldn't change significantly.

Comment: Considering how close 1.7 is to release (now), I'd probably skip the 1.6.x versions unless you really need the functionality.  Upgrading from one version to another never seems to be a "free" exercise and 1.7 is a version you will definitely want to use because of the integration of migrations to the framework and the way 3rd party apps will probably use that newer versions.  Having said this, I just upgraded to 1.6 because of issues with the 3rd party testrunner and 1.5.x (which was solved by 1.6).